# How to find variable name from string-array on strings.xml

Tags: android, kotlin

Maybe this is a bit complicated but I have an Kotlin Android Studio app that says the year and the month the car was registered based on the Letters of the 2 letters of the license plate.

The letters goes AA to ZZ (example: AA, AB, AC ... AZ, BA, BB ... ZX ZZ)

and I have in the file strings.xml the values stored

Example:

```
 <string-array name='AP'>
        <item>2005</item>
        <item>9</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name='AQ'>
        <item>2005</item>
        <item>9</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name='AR'>
        <item>2005</item>
        <item>10</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name='AS'>
        <item>2005</item>
        <item>10</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name='AT'>
        <item>2005</item>
        <item>10</item>
   </string-array>
    <string-array name='AU'>
        <item>2005</item>
        <item>11</item>
    </string-array>
```

Then, based in the user input on EditText checks the letters and finds on the Strings.xml

The problem is if I do

```
when (x) {
    "AA" -> print("x == 1")
    "AB" -> print("x == 2")
    .....
}
```

will result in 529 lines of code just to check the the letters on the license plate...

My question is if there is an better and tidier way of doing this, like this:

```
 val stringArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array."EditText.getText()")
```

Sounds complicated... and I'm an beginner in Kotlin

Comment: Store those string array in JSON format. It will be more easy to parse and lightweight.

Comment: Do the values have to be stored as resources?

Comment: Tried several times but JSON is way too much complicated to implement... Just used a when case to an array.

Answer (score 0):

String array resources are constants. You can't call R.array.somevariable. You should use [XML parser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) instead.